# Check MySQL status

Tags: mysql, connection, ping

I am experiencing a slow connection on a website that I am developing and MySQL errors from time to time.

How do I check MySQL server status? Is there something like ping from cmdprompt in Win?

Thanks

Comment: So you need to check if server is down?

Comment: You want to check the ping or do you want to check if the server is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a php file for connection to any database and program for returning the connection status like

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
if ($conn){
echo "Connection is alive";
}
else{
echo "failed to connect server: ".mysql_error();
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

upload as to test.php and open in browser // this is the easiest way